# Whether the answer is right or wrong, my score and counter are constantly increasing. Idont want this

Tags: c#, .net, maui, android-mvvm, maui-community-toolkit

Using the MVVM Design Pattern I am developing a basic operations math application.When I give a wrong answer, my score and counter score increase as if I answered correctly. I used some artificial intelligence to solve this but still no solution. That's why I decided to ask here. I would be glad if you help.

MultiplicationPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Models"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.Views.MultiplicationPage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MultiplicationPageViewModel"
             Title="MultiplicationPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Score: " FontSize="18" />
            <Label Text="{Binding playerModal.Score}" FontSize="18" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Time Remaining: " FontSize="18" />
            <Label Text="{Binding playerModal.TimeReaming}" FontSize="18" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Question: " FontSize="18" />
            <Label Text="{Binding playerModal.Question}" FontSize="18" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter Your Answer" Text="{Binding playerModal.Answer}" FontSize="18" />
        
        <Button Text="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitAnswerCommand }" FontSize="18" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MultiplicationPageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MauiApp2.Models;
using MauiApp2.Services;
using MauiApp2.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MultiplicationPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PlayerModal> PlayerDetails { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PlayerModal>();
        public PlayerModal playerModal { get; set; } = new PlayerModal();
        public ICommand SubmitAnswerCommand { get; }
        public MultiplicationPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            
            playerModal.Score = 0;
            playerModal.TimeReaming= 60;
            SubmitAnswerCommand = new Command(SubmitAnswer);

            // Create a question as an example
            GenerateQuestion();
            // Start the timer
            StartTimer();
        }
        
        [RelayCommand]
        public void GenerateQuestion()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int number1 = random.Next(1, 11); // a random number between 1 and 10
            int number2 = random.Next(1, 11); // a random number between 1 and 10

            // playerModal.Answer = (number1 * number2).ToString(); Automatic Answer
            playerModal.Question = $"{number1} x {number2}"; 
        }
        public async void StartTimer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // wait 1 sec
                playerModal.TimeReaming--;

                if (playerModal.TimeReaming == 0)
                {
                    if (playerModal.Score > playerModal.HighScore)
                    {
                        playerModal.HighScore = playerModal.Score; // Update high score
                    }
                    GameOver(); // Finish the game when time is up
                }
            }
        }

        public void SubmitAnswer()
        {
            if (int.TryParse(playerModal.Answer, out int userAnswer))
            {
                int correctAnswer = int.Parse(playerModal.Answer);
                if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
                {
                    playerModal.Score += 10;
                    playerModal.TimeReaming += 5;

                }
                else
                {
                    playerModal.Score -= 10;
                    playerModal.TimeReaming -= 5;

                    // Negative score and time control
                    if (playerModal.Score < 0)
                    {
                        playerModal.Score = 0;
                    }
                    if (playerModal.TimeReaming < 0)
                    {
                        playerModal.TimeReaming = 0;
                    }
                }

                GenerateQuestion();
            }

            playerModal.Answer = "";

            // Check earned score and update new high score
            if (playerModal.Score > playerModal.HighScore)
            {
                playerModal.HighScore = playerModal.Score;
            }
        }

        public async void GameOver()
        {
           await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync(nameof(GameOverPage));
        }
    }
}
```

PlayerModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiApp2.Models
{
    public partial class PlayerModal : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        int score;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int highScore;
        [ObservableProperty]
        int timeReaming;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string answer;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string question;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you are parsing `playerModal.Answer` and assigning it to `userAnswer`

```
if (int.TryParse(playerModal.Answer, out int userAnswer))
```

then, you **again** parse `playerModal.Answer` and assign it to `correctAnswer`

```
int correctAnswer = int.Parse(playerModal.Answer);
```

finally, you compare `userAnswer` and `correctAnswer`

```
if (userAnswer == correctAnswer)
```

they will **always match** no matter what the user answers

```
a = z;
b = z;

if (a == b) will always be true
```

instead do something like

```
correctAnswer = (number1 * number2).ToString();
```